# Windows Form C++ Cсылка на неразрешенный внешний символ в функции Getpixel

Tags: c++, winforms

Всем привет. Пишу код в windows form и при вызове функции GetPixel ошибка:
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "extern "C" unsigned long __ stdcall GetPixel(struct HDC__ *,int,int)" (?GetPixel@@$$J212YGKPAUHDC__@@HH@Z)
Почему она появляется? Как ее решить?

```
#pragma comment(lib, "user32")

#include "MAINCPP.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThreadAttribute]
void maincpp(cli::array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    CLPJ21::MAINCPP form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}

System::Void CLPJ21::MAINCPP::button1_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    int R, G, B;
    POINT p;
    HDC dc = GetDC(NULL);
    COLORREF color = GetPixel(dc, p.x, p.y);
    R = GetRValue(color);
    G = GetGValue(color);
    B = GetBValue(color);
    return System::Void();

}
```